# Copy column from excel to array in python

Tags: python, excel

I have values in an excel sheet that I want to easily transfer to my Python code. Is there any easy way to select all the cells you want from the sheet and then copy-paste them into the text editor with each cell value separated with a comma?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with either MATLAB or google-sheets. Please do not tag-spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `pandas` to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xslx', sheetname='your_sheet_name')
your_array = df['your_column_name'].toarray()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you copy-paste a column, the values will be seperated by a line break. You can seperate it, by the Python REPL, if you assign it to a string variable (using triple quote), then use `a = yourstring.split()` to seperate the values to an array, and then `a.join(',')` to split by a comma, as a string parsed values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing the process too often you can copy to a text editor e.g. notepad ++ and then do a find and replace for new line ('\r\n') to ',' with extended search mode.

[image]